# get children of all previous elements with jquery

Tags: jquery

So this seems to be more complicated in my head than it needs to be. I need to find a way to `addClass('selected');` to a specific child of all previous elements. Let's say my HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="radio">
    <div class="child">
      <span>1</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="radio">
    <div class="child">
      <span>2</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="radio">
    <div class="child">
      <span>3</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="radio">
    <div class="child">
      <span>4</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="radio">
    <div class="child">
      <span>5</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now, when I click on "4", I'd have something like this:

```
$('.radio span').click(function(){
  $('.radio span').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

This works fine, as it adds the class to the 4th one. I need it to also select the spans in all the li's prior to 4. I tried:

```
$(this).closest('li.radio').prevAll().children('span').addClass('selected');
```

but it doesn't seem to want to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.find` to get the `span` since it isn't a child of the `li` (it's a descendant).

```
$(this).closest('li.radio').prevAll().find('span').addClass('selected');
```

you should chain it off of addClass:

```
$(this).addClass('selected').closest('li.radio').prevAll().find('span').addClass('selected');
```

Comment: Wonderful, works like a charm! I'll accept when it lets me :D